# edge transitive

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a graph all of whose edge-deleted subgraphs are isomorphic. Is $G$
necessarily edge-transitive?

I checked the following link but in the end they conclude without good justification what happens if the graph is bipartite. Could you please help me? I have a hard time understanding this exercise.

[Edge-deleted subgraphs and edge transitivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245845/edge-deleted-subgraphs-and-edge-transitivity/3245877#3245877)

Answer (score 0):

I think the argument is true.

Following the aforementioned claim(hyperlink), we may assume that $G$ is [a bipartite graph with a bipartition $(A,B)$ and $\deg a = d+1$ and $\deg b = d$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$] $\cdots(*)$.
By the given condition that all edge-deleted subgraphs are isomorphic, we can describe $G-e$ where $e\in E(G)$.
Denote $e=vw$ with $v\in A$ and $w\in B$.
There are three types of vertices of $G-e$: $\deg = d+1$, $d$, $d-1$.
Of course, $\deg_{G-e} v = d$ and $\deg_{G-e} w = d-1$.
Remind that $N(v) \subseteq B$, where $N(v)$ is the set of neighbors of $v$.

If we add an edge $f$ in $G-e$ which is incident with $w$, there is only one option that $G-e+f$ is isomorphic to $G$, $f=e$.
Otherwise, $G-e+f$ cannot satisfy (*).
It implies that $G$ is edge-transitive.

Comment: I just wondered that the statement holds for vertex case. Q: If $G-v \cong G-w$ for all $v,w\in V(G)$, then $G$ is vertex-transitive. I concluded that this is true by a similar degree sequence argument. In this problem, $G$ satisfying the given condition is always a regular graph.

Comment: yes, for the vertex case it is true. On the other hand, retaking the edge case, what happens if $\deg{a}>d+1$ and $\deg{b}=d$? Because you just analized the equality case

Comment: In that case, similarly, there are four possible degrees for $G-e$: $k = \deg a$, $k-1$, $l = \deg b$, $l-1$. There is only one vertex with degree $k-1$ in $G-e$, which is an end-vertex of $e$. Same for degree $l-1$. Hence there is only one option for recovering $G$ by adding an edge into $G-e$. It implies that $G$ is edge-transitive.